# I need 10 rows instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this code, which adds a new row every time I click on the button, but i want to start with 10 rows instead of 1. Is there anyone who knows how I can do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Regel verwijderen</a><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="text"/></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
  <form>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <input type="button" name="plus" value="Regel toevoegen" class="add_field_button btn">
      <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="text"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Done" class="submit btn">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML also

Comment: Why not simply emit 10 text fields when you render the page from your PHP (or what-have-you)? If all you have is static html, then you could hardcode the inputs there.

Comment: [We all have jobs to do. It may be homework, or for assigned work at our job. No matter what, it’s our responsibility to get it done. Even when it seems like our task is too hard or we don’t know where to start, **it is always worth the effort to at least try**.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @Liam 1 link would've been enough

Comment: i updated my code now and profided my html

Comment: Your HTML will be more valid if you change `<div class="width">
  <form>` to `<form><div class="width">`

Comment: Great you've now added a MCVE, well done. But this question still lacks effort. Have you attempted to fix this yourself? It reads like you're just hoping someone will do your work for you.

Comment: Well Liam i just started with this type of coding so no i am not hoping someone will do the work for me i just need some help...

Comment: You cache the `wrapper` jQuery object, then you rebuild another jQuery object from it with `$(wrapper)`. Same for `add_button`. What's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var defrow = 10 // default rows
  var max_fields = 15 // maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap') // Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $('.add_field_button') // Add button ID

  var x = 1 // initlal text box count
  Array(defrow)
    .fill()
    .forEach(function () {
      $(wrapper).append(
        '<div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Regel verwijderen</a><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="text"/></div>'
      ) // add input box
    })
  $(add_button).click(function (e) {
    // on add input button click
    e.preventDefault()
    if (x < max_fields) {
      // max input box allowed
      x++ // text box increment
      $(wrapper).append(
        '<div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Regel verwijderen</a><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="text"/></div>'
      ) // add input box
    }
  })

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function (e) {
    // user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this)
      .parent('div')
      .remove()
    x--
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_field_button">button</button>
<div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
```

I add this code :

```
  Array(defrow)
    .fill()
    .forEach(function () {
      $(wrapper).append(
        '<div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Regel verwijderen</a><input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="text"/></div>'
      ) // add input box
    })
```